# Unable to update child component state after updating parent component state through callback

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to update the state of the parent component through a callback in the onPress function of a child component and then update the state of the child component itself. However, I am only able to either update state of the parent component or the child component but not both in sequence. The code concerning my issue is listed below:

```js
export default class GameScreen extends React.Component {
  
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nextOne: 'X'
    }
    this.nextOneCallback = this.nextOneCallback.bind(this);
  }
  nextOneCallback () {
    this.setState({
      nextOne: 'Y'
    });
  }
  render() {
    const ticTacToeSquare = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      const rowArray = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        const newBox = (<TicTacToeBox key = {Math.random(10000)} callback={this.nextOneCallback}/>);
        rowArray.push(newBox);
      }
      const eachRenderedRow = (
        <View key = {Math.random(10000)} style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            {rowArray}
        </View>
      );
      ticTacToeSquare.push(eachRenderedRow);
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        {ticTacToeSquare}
        <Button
          title="Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class TicTacToeBox extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: '',
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{ borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 2, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} >
        <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', height: 40, width: 40}} maxLength={1} onPress={
          () => {
            this.setState((prevState, props) => ({text: 'X'}));
            // this.props.callback();
          }
        }>
          {this.state.text}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The onPress function of the TicTacToeBox does not behave as expected. Any help on how I can update the parent state and then the child state will be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're creating new instances of `TicTacToeBox` every time you update the state on `GameScreen`, so even though `setState` runs on the `TicTacToeBox`, it's meaningless since that instance get thrown away and a new one is rendered by `GameScreen`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Does that mean that there is no way for a child component to retain it's existing state when a parent state is updated?

Comment: Not at all, there are alternatives. You can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent child components to re-render automatically after the parent's state is updated, or lift the state up to the parent, or implement `getDerivedStateFromProps`... it really depends on your use-case which one you end up choosing. In this case you should avoid creating new instances of `TicTacToe` all over the place and place them under the return from your `render`, that can help you (and react) to have a more consistent output

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value you want to update to child also

```
<TicTacToeBox key = {Math.random(10000)} callback={this.nextOneCallback}  nextOne={this.state.nextOne}/>);
```

then extract this value in child using props

`this.props.nextOne` in the child

So whenever you will hit the callback function from child the value will get updated in both parent and child.